# How to display only a left and bottom box border in matplotlib?

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data in matplotlib. I would like to hide the upper and right parts of the box. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Joe: Thanks I didn't know about the concept of 'spines' in Matplotlib.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just set the spines (and/or ticks) to be invisible.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to hide the ticks on the top and left as well, just do:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Consider also this option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create your plot with your code
# Then extract the spines and make them invisible
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.show() # Show your plot
```

or just

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create your plot with your code
# Then extract the spines and make them invisible
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.show() # Show your plot
```

Hope it helps somebody